# what is it if the Fourier series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos 2n\pi x}{n^{s+1}}$

Tags: polynomials, fourier-series

I guess that if $s$ is positive odd integer, then Fourier series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos 2n\pi x}{n^{s+1}}$$
is a polynomial of degree $s+1$. For example, if $s=1$, then

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos 2n\pi x}{n^2} = c(x^2- x + \frac{1}{6})$$

If $s\geq 0$ is even integer, then Fourier series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin 2n\pi x}{n^{s+1}}$$
is a polynomial of degree $s+1$. For example, if $s = 0$, then 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin 2n\pi x}{n} = c(x-\frac{1}{2})$$

I need your confirmation.

Comment: Well, it's the periodic extension of the restriction of a polynomial to $[0,1)$. Prove it by induction on $s$, noting that for $s > 1$, you can differentiate the Fourier series termwise.

Comment: This [comment and thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411312/closed-form-of-a-series-dilogarithm#comment2876490_1411312) and this [Bernoulli polynomials link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Fourier_series) may help too.

Comment: Please define c()

Comment: I think $c(x-\frac{1}{2})$ means: "a constant multiple of $x-\frac{1}{2}$."

Comment: Yes, it is Bernoulli polynomial of degree $s+1$. Thank you for the link.