# A closed form for a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

This maybe duplicated, please let me know if it is so.
I would like to find a closed form for the following sum
$$ \sum_k \frac {1}{k^2}\cos (kx)$$
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: [Answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9AeaZ.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a [Bernoulli polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#Relation_to_the_Bernoulli_Polynomials)  $\;B_2(x)\;$ up to a constant $\pi^2$ for $\,x \in (0,2\pi)$ :

\begin{align}
S&:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {\cos (kx)}{k^2}\\
&=\pi^2\;B_2\left(\frac x{2\pi}\right)\\
&=\pi^2\;\left(\left(\frac x{2\pi}\right)^2-\frac x{2\pi}+\frac 16\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac{\pi x}2+\frac{x^2}4\\
\end{align}

On the other side if you replace the $\cos$ function by a $\sin$ you would get a non elementary Clausen function $Cl_2$. For some (nontrivial) intuition about all this you may see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/121376/21783) or [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411312) or this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1210687/21783).