# Calculate $ \int_0^{2\pi} \ln(2-2\cos(t)) \ln(2-2\cos(t+\theta)) dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \ln(2-2\cos(t)) \ln(2-2\cos(t+\theta)) dt$$

but I'm not sure the best way to proceed.  I've been trying to factor the inner terms in to rational functions of $e^{it}$ and use logarithm identities to split the integral in to the sum of simpler complex integrals, but to limited success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This integral has an expression in terms of special functions.

Using the fact that

$$-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}=\ln(2|\sin(x/2)|)$$

the above integral can be directly rewritten as

$$I=4 \int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln\Big(2\Big|\sin\frac{t}{2}\Big|\Big)\ln\Big(2\Big|\sin\frac{t+\theta}{2}\Big|\Big)dt=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4}{mn}\int_{0}^{2\pi}dt~\cos(nt)\cos(mt+m\theta)$$

However it is true that

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}dt~\cos(nt)\cos(mt+m\theta)=\pi\cos m\theta(\delta_{m+n,0}+\delta_{m-n,0})$$

and thus the desired quantity reduces to

$$I(\theta)=4\pi\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos n\theta}{n^2}=2\pi\Big[\text{Li}_2(e^{i\theta})+\text{Li}_2(e^{-i\theta})\Big]$$

It seems that from this very simple form, a simpler one is unattainable, however, finding particular values of the integral in terms of known constants is not impossible. For example

$$I(0)=4\pi \zeta(2)=\frac{2\pi^3}{3}\\I(\pi)=-2\pi\zeta(2)=-\frac{\pi^3}{3}$$

EDIT:

It is actually not difficult to obtain a closed form for this sum as in here (thanks @Jay Lemmon for catching this).

Here's a way to show it different from the one cited on the link:

We know that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin nx}{n}=\frac{\pi-x}{2}~~, x\in(0,2\pi)$$

Integrating this equation in $[0,\theta]$ we obtain

$$-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos n\theta}{n^2}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\frac{\pi \theta}{2}-\frac{\theta^2}{4}$$

which shows that the integral in question has a very simple form

$$I(\theta)=\pi\theta^2-2\pi^2\theta+\frac{2\pi^3}{3}$$

Comment: Thanks!  Expressing it in terms of dilogarithms is sufficient for my purposes.

Comment: Actually, according to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1411312/8964 it looks like you can express it as $\frac{2}{3} \pi^3 - 2 \pi^2 \theta + \pi \theta^2$

Comment: I should have seen that simplification!